# JSON not able to parse byte array when it is too long in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, afnetworking

I had an iPhone application on which i am taking pdf data as byte array from server with in a loop.I need to call the service multiple times to get the byte array there it self i am writing that to document.But after some time its getting automatically closed,i assume thats is happening becoz of memory issues ,here is the code i am trying

```
dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

    for (int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++)

    {
                // Enter the group for each request we create
        dispatch_group_enter(group);
        NSString *path=[NSString stringWithFormat:@“%@dsdsdsdsd”,url];
        NSError *error;
        NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:@{@“sass”:[array objectAtIndex:i]} options:0 error:&error];
        NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@",jsonString);

        AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
        manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes =  [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript",@"text/html", nil];
        AFJSONResponseSerializer *responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];

        [manager setResponseSerializer:responseSerializer];

        [manager POST:path parameters:jsonString progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject)
         {

             NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);

             NSArray *responseObjectstr=[responseObject valueForKey:@""];
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{


             if(responseObjectstr.count>0)
             {

                 @autoreleasepool
                 {

             NSDictionary *dict=[responseObjectstr objectAtIndex:0];
             NSArray *byteArray=[dict valueForKey:@“fffffff”];

            unsigned c = byteArray.count;
             uint8_t *bytes = malloc(sizeof(*bytes) * c);

             unsigned i;
             for (i = 0; i < c; i++)
             {
                 NSString *str = [byteArray objectAtIndex:i];
                 int byte = [str intValue];
                 bytes[i] = (uint8_t)byte;
             }

             NSData* data = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)bytes length:sizeof(unsigned char)*c];
             NSString *docsDir;
             NSArray *dirPaths;

             dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
             docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];


             NSError *error;
             NSArray *ipaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
             NSString *idocumentsDir = [ipaths objectAtIndex:0];
             NSString *idataPath = [idocumentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[dict valueForKey:@"fff"]];
             NSLog(@"idataPath:%@",idataPath);

             //Create folder here
             if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:idataPath])
             {



                 NSString *databasePath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[dict valueForKey:@"fff"]]];
                 [data writeToFile:databasePath atomically:YES];
             }
             }
             }
                   });
             dispatch_group_leave(group);

         }
              failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error)
         {
             dispatch_group_leave(group);
         }];

        }


    // Here we wait for all the requests to finish
    dispatch_group_notify(group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    });
```

But after 3 responses nothing is happening just going struck Can anybody help me to find where i am going wrong?

Comment: How big is the PDF document you are testing with? You might be running out of thread memory and you may want to look into handling your requests differently.

Comment: 60 mb files of number 10.is it better to download by url request?